# What does the phrase "be faced" mean?

Tags: meaning

It's from the tenth episode of the sixth season of *Friends*. Here is the context and [video](https://youtu.be/XYRue0GUIsg). It's at 1 minute and 48 seconds.

> Hey, I know what’ll get us up on a platform!
>
> Monica: What?
>
> Ross: The routine!
>
> Monica: Ross, we haven’t done the routine since middle school.
>
> Ross: Hey, when the snippy guy sees the routine, he’ll wanna build us
>   our own platform!
>
> Monica: Was it really that good?
>
> Ross: We got honourable mention in the brother/sister dance category!
>   Look, it’s almost fake midnight, do we really have any other choice?
>
> Monica: Okay, let’s do it. Mom and Dad are gonna **be so faced**!

Comment: Honestly, that slang doesn't make much sense to me either.  Without further context, I can't help.  Honestly sounds like an attempt of the writers of Friends to try and introduce a new term to pop culture that failed...

Comment: Yeah, this is not standard slang that I know of. Part of the point of this scene is that Ross and Monica are deeply "uncool" (despite thinking they are very cool!), so this could be Monica trying and failing to use slang.  It's also very possible that this is a reference to some joke that was set up earlier in the same episode.

Comment: Might be from the slang term, a single-word interjection, "Face!".  Urban Dictionary: Interjection commonly used after a person has been insulted, disgraced, or humiliated. Derived from the phrase "in your face."